# Why are some behaviours not/less addictive than others even though they bring great pleasure?

Tags: addiction

I'm wondering why some behaviour like gambling is highly addictive, while playing soccer/basketball etc, despite clearly being pleasurable given their popularity seem much less so.

Ive never seen anybody excuse themselves from a dinner to kick a ball outside but have with gambling. What is unique to things such as gambling that other pleasurable activities lack?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a valid answer, so I post this as a comment. I recently finished reading a book called "Irresistible: The Rise of Addictive Technology and the Business of Keeping Us Hooked". It will likely answer your question.